# VBA - Overflow Error only when using property of custom object

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a `Player` object that holds a `Long` property Wealth that must be assigned to a cell in Excel, but I get the Overflow runtime error only when the last line references `newPlayer.Wealth` and not when the value is set to a fixed number greater than the max integer. Here is the code:

```
For i = 68 To (67 + numPlayers)
    Dim newPlayer As New Player
    newPlayer.Wealth = CLng(40000)
    newPlayer.Number = i - 67
    Range(Chr(i) & "2").Value = "Player " & CStr(newPlayer.Number)
    Range(Chr(i) & "3").Value = newPlayer.Wealth
Next
```

This works, however:

```
Range(Chr(i) & "3").Value = CLng(40000)
```

I tried to clear formatting from the cell that I'm specifying but I still have problems. What is the reason for this? Here is also my class properties:

```
Private pNumber As Integer
Private pProperties As New Collection
Private pWealth As Long

Property Get Number() As Integer
    Number = pNumber
End Property

Property Let Number(pNum As Integer)
    pNumber = pNum
End Property

Property Get Properties() As Collection
    Properties = pProperties
End Property

Property Get Wealth() As Long
    Number = pWealth
End Property

Property Let Wealth(w As Long)
    pWealth = w
End Property

Public Sub addProperty(property As PropertyUnit)
    pProperties.Add (property)
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be important to see your class definition and Let/Get.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your class definition.

This appears wrong. Beyond the copy/paste from Get Number() error, shoving a 40K long into a signed integer is going to overflow.

```
Private pNumber As Integer
Private pWealth As Long
...

Property Get Wealth() As Long
    Number = pWealth
End Property
```

Change to something like,

```
...
Private pWealth As Long

Property Get Wealth() As Long
    Wealth= pWealth
End Property

Property Let Wealth(Value As Long)
    pWealth = Value 
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jeeped pointed out `Property Get Wealth()` needs to be modified like this:

```
Property Get Wealth() As Long
    Wealth = pWealth
End Property
```

A couple of other points.

There is no reason to cast the number to string for the address concatenations.   The VBA will do that automatically.  `Range(Chr(i) & "2").Value` and `Range(Chr(i) & 2).Value` are effectively the same.

There is no reason to cast a number into long.  CLng(40000) or 40000 will work.

`Dim newPlayer As New Player` inside a loop will only create a single instance of the `Player` class.  Declare `newPlayer` outside of the loop and use `Set newPlayer = New Player` inside the loop to create more instances of `newPlayer`.

`Range(Chr(i) & "2")` will work as long as you don't have more then more than 22 players.  I prefer `Cells(2, i + 4).Value`.

```
Dim newPlayer As New Player
numPlayers = 10
For i = 1 To numPlayers
    Set newPlayer = New Player
    newPlayer.Wealth = CLng(40000)
    newPlayer.Number = i
    Cells(2, i + 4).Value = "Player " & CStr(newPlayer.Number)
    Cells(2, i + 5).Value = newPlayer.Wealth
Next
```